# Scaling out Search Crawl service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawling, configuration, crawl

I have a large content database on a Sharepoint 2010 site collection (130GB).

The search crawl component which has a job to index items in the site collection is taking too long and in the process eats up all the CPU.

A suggestion I found online was to create a second crawl component on a separate sever to crawl the same crawl DB.

My question is... do I install Sharepoint 2010 on another server and then only activate crawl component etc. How do I configure this second Sharepoint server?

Also, is there any other way I can use this second server? (seems a bit overkill just to use it to crawl).

many thanks,

KS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crawling is one of the most resource intense services you can use in SharePoint. That's why we in the first place would like to have an application server in our three tier topology setup. One for Front-End, one for Applications and one for Databases.

As content grow over time it will take longer and longer time to crawl with an already resource intense applications. If you don't have an application tier in your farm, that would be your first step to increase performance.

Install SharePoint 2010 on the new application tier, set up all services with appropriate managed accounts or local services, and stop all your services on the front end server (at non-office hours). Start the services on your application tier and verify that your services are running correct (Timer job history, click success/failed to see what happened).

Measure performance the following days, and see how things evolve. You may need a second Front End, different RAID setup, fiber channel network access, dedicated network card on SQL server and stuff like that to make performance increase even further. Good Luck (and ask again if needed)

Comment: Thx for the response. So it looks like I have to provision a 2nd server and install Sharepoint with Search Service. Then, on this server I can create the number of craw components that I require. Would this be correct?

Comment: @Perplexed true that! When done, monitor all SP server performance and balance load between them by moving services around. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It consist of the following steps:

- Add application server to the existing farm. To add application server to the farm follow MSDN [Add a Web or application server to the farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752.aspx)
- Configure [Search service application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

---

In case of search architecture further options might be considered, like scale out of Search components

### Configure Search components

Search components

- query (query components, index partitions)
- crawling (crawl component, crawl database)

can be scaled out separately ([Manage search topology](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428104%28v=office.14%29.aspx))